# How does cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser() work?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My questions is regarding AWS Cognito SDK.  My front-end authenticates the user with amplify /cognito and sends the token in the header to my backend.

I have successfully used cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser() to get user attributes on my backend nodejs app, but without any permissions!

I am using a restricted user with only S3 and SES permissions on my API, but I am just surprised, the getUser() call just decode the JWT token without any authorisation? and if so, can anyone decode all user attributes from my jwt token using aws-sdk?

I also removed the API key entirely on the backend, just to see and it was still able get the user object successfully. Is this not a security risk?

Code:

```
   const aws = require('aws-sdk');
   var provider =  new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
   const user = await provider.getUser( {AccessToken: jwtToken}).promise();
   return user;
```

Comment: Anyone can decode token, even without SDK, there are plenty of online tools like [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/). But no-one can forge or create it until he has a secret.